# On locally small category

Tags: set-theory, category-theory

Maybe this is a very trivial question for those who are familiar with Set theory.

Let $C$ be a category, and $\hat{C}$ be its presheaves.

I hear that if both $C$ and $\hat{C}$ are locally small, then $C$ is small.

I'm not familiar with the usage of ZFC-axioms, so I'm not sure if this is true.

If this is true, which axioms of ZFC imply this?

Comment: The result is proven here in about 3 pages. http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/v1n9.pdf